# button text doesn't appear when rotate emulator

Tags: android, fragment, screen-rotation, android-savedstate

I have an activity that contain a fragment which contains a recycler view and i use recycler view adapter to fill the recycler view with data and i use layout which contains 2 text view and 3 buttons when rotate emulator the language changed so I save the state of the fragment in activity, the language doesn't changed but the text on buttons doesn't appear I try to save state of text in fragment but i get error null pointer exception for button object

the fragment code

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_azkaar_fragment,container, false);
    rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewcard);
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);
    activity = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("activity", 3);
    position = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 3);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.scrollToPosition(position);
    settings= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    favourite=loadArray("fav",getActivity());
    favourite_evening=loadArray("fav_evening",getActivity());

    for(int i=0;i<favourite.length;i++)
        Log.d("msg ",String.valueOf(favourite[i]));
    if (settings.getBoolean("is_first_time_presses", true)) {
        //the app is being launched for first time, do something
        Log.d("TAG", "First time Presses");
        settings.edit().putBoolean("is_first_time_presses", false).commit();
        storePresses(presses,"presses",0);
        storePresses(presses_evening,"presses_evening",0);
    } else {
        //second time launch..
        presses=loadPresses("presses");
        presses_evening=loadPresses("presses_evening");
        for(int i=0;i<presses.length;i++)
            Log.d("presses ",String.valueOf(presses[i]));
    }
    if (settings.getBoolean("is_sett", true)) {
        //the app is being launched for first time, do something
        Log.d("TAG", "First time");
        settings.edit().putBoolean("is_sett", false).commit();
        storeArraySettings(settingsArray,"sett",true,getActivity());
    } else {
        //second time launch..
        settingsArray=loadArray("sett",getActivity());
        for(int i=0;i<settingsArray.length;i++)
            Log.d("msg ",String.valueOf(settingsArray[i]));
    }
    if(activity == 3){
        azkarForms=getSunsetFavourites("fav","presses", this.getContext());
        adapter=new RecyclerFavouriteAdapter(azkarForms,getActivity(),activity,0);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
    }
    else{
        azkarForms=getSunsetFavourites("fav_evening","presses_evening", this.getContext());
        adapter=new RecyclerFavouriteAdapter(azkarForms,getActivity(),activity,0);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button next=view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        next.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("next"));
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
    }
    return view;
}
private ArrayList<AzkarForm> getSunsetFavourites(String arrayName, String pressesArray, Context mContext) {
    AzkaarData azkaarData = new AzkaarData(mContext);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = settings.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);
    Boolean[] array = new Boolean[size];
    int[] numPresses = new int[size];

    ArrayList<MyFavourites> myResults = new ArrayList<MyFavourites>();
    MyFavourites myFavourites;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = settings.getBoolean(arrayName + "_" + i, true);
        numPresses[i] = settings.getInt(pressesArray + "_" + i, 0);

            myFavourites=new MyFavourites(i,array[i],numPresses[i]);
            myResults.add(myFavourites);

    }
    if (myResults != null)
        list = azkaarData.getArrayListDataFav(myResults,activity, 0);
    return list;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
    savedInstanceState.putString("next", next.getText().toString());
}
```

adapter code

```
} else if (activity == 3) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_details,parent,false);
    holder=new MyViewHolder(view,activity,c);
    return holder;
} else if (activity == 4) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_details,parent,false);
    holder=new MyViewHolder(view,activity,c);
    return holder;
}
```

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:weightSum="6">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:src="@drawable/favorite_border"
                android:clickable="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="@string/add_zekr_txt"
                android:textSize="26sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:layout_weight="4">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/relative">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sample"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/sample_zekr"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview"
            android:weightSum="5">
            <Button
                android:text="3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/btnborder"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            <Button
                android:text="@string/num_press"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/press"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btncircle"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            <Button
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/btnborder"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewcard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: attach layout file.

Comment: I attach layout of fragment and layout sample that will appear in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Use override method `onConfigurationChanged()` that will help you with orientation change problems.